Identifying Low Water Pressure Problem
We experience low water pressure in the entire house with the following problems:

Ground floor: Low pressure and no warm water to kitchen and bathroom faucets
1st Floor: Low pressure to faucet and shower but with warm water (slow to get warm), and another problem is when someone uses another faucet the shower gets boiling hot (dangerous).

I have made a sketch of the system and can provide more pictures, but I have identified that there are multiple possible problems:

Pressure regulator is faulty (Gauge shows 3 even when setting is at 4)
Water filter needs replacing
Circulating pump from water tank/boiler to oil boiler is not in fact circulating (makes no sound and are very warm to the touch)
Gauge above oil boiler shows slightly below 1 bar which I assume is a bit to little.

However elements in the house are all warm and functioning.
I have no experience but I need to learn this so please if anyone has a clue on what I can try to get more pressure or which device I should replace, please let me know.


What type of piping? New problem or old problem? Age of system?

Any reason you haven't worked through your list of possibilities, maybe cheapest first? You seem to be avoiding the D of DIY. The first two seem like great candidates.

Generally the pressure gauge on a boiler is indicating the pressure of the heating loop, which is separate and isolated from domestic hot water even if domestic hot water is also heated by the boiler, so 1 bar is probably a perfectly reasonable number there (unless you have a 3 story house with the boiler in the basement.)

Regarding circulator pump not circulating: We had a pump that had a bubble of air in it. It was working crazy hard (and running SUPER hot) and moving no water. We had to stop the pump and drain some water through it to clear the bubble and reprime it.

@JACK I am unfortunately unable to answer that as I genuinly have no idea about this, but I think it is a older system but well maintained.

@isherwood I am not in the right position to try and fail at the moment during the holidays. I will try the two first tomorrow!

@Ecnerwal OK that is good to know because the heating elements are heated very well and a plumber was here last year for this. But was unaware of the pressure problem.

Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers appropriately. "Thanks" and your intentions aren't really what comments are for.


if anyone has a clue on what I can try to get more pressure or which device


ok.  remove the pressure regulator.  This is likely the best fix.

ok.  There should be a bypass to the filter, if it was installed properly.  Otherwise remove the filter and run it without a filter and then you'll know the significance of the pressure reduction caused by it.  Which can be your problem.

if it was "in fact" not circulating, then you would not have hot water.  They are quiet and you cannot tell it's running.

the piping on the boiler side, with the circulator, is a closed system, separate from your "potable" water to your faucets.  It should be around 15 psi, or 1 bar.


if the regulator gauge is accurate showing "3 bar" which is 45 psi, that is primarily your problem.  Even 60 psi (4 bar) sucks.  For every 2 feet up you will lose 1 psi of pressure.  Ask yourself why you even need a pressure reducing valve.  Millions of homes running 90-100 psi city water pressure, no pressure regulator, just fine with no complaints.
If your shower valve(s) or faucets is not a thermostatic pressure balancing type, then that's why it gets super hot when other faucets are run, and that will always happen.  If it is, then that valve is bad, depending on the make/model you might be able to (or have a plumber) replace the cartridge in it rather than outright replacement of the entire shower valve.  google/youtube shower valve types.  Also boiler circulator hydronic piping.

Thank you for your answer! I will definitely try to up the pressure regulator to 5 bar and see what happens, if it is faulty then I will replace it. I don’t know how to bypass it so I will try to remove it and run it without the filter.
